# jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-easing

I am getting below error when I look in the console:

```
jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
```

I am trying to make a slider on WordPress. I am working on a localhost so I can't exactly show whats up. However, when the slider is just in an HTML file outside of WordPress it works. When in WordPress, it is giving me that error. Any insight into what the problem could be will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code. We can't debug invisible code.

Comment: This blog post help me, now it works for me : [http://www.gilluminate.com/2011/06/06/jquery-easingjquery-easing-def-is-not-a-function/](http://www.gilluminate.com/2011/06/06/jquery-easingjquery-easing-def-is-not-a-function/)

Answer (score 54):

To save everyone some time. Open your Jquery easing plugin file and wrap the code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Code goes here...
});
```

Comment: I only get the issue when using it with CommonJS/browserify but this solution fixed it.

Comment: "Open your Jquery easing plugin file" -- where is the location of that file? does it come with wordpress or is it something assumed to be manually installed? thanks :)

Comment: @aequalsb In inspect element, where the error is printed, hover with your mouse on the filename and it will show you the full path.

Comment: Does anyone know why when I do `$(document)` it works, but if I do `jQuery(document)` it does not?

Comment: @Lemures how can i see the OP's error when the code is not presented nor a URL to view the error... i think you misunderstood... i was suggesting action for the OP

Answer (score 27):

Please check that whether you are loading jQuery more than once. If you have inserted in the footer manually, try removing it.

Comment: This was it for me! A plugin from october cms was injecting its own jquery alongside the one I had included myself.

Answer (score 22):

The problem is

```
swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
}
```

jQuery in this function could not be equal to the jQuery, where `jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,` has been applied.

1. replace `jQuery` with `$`
2. wrap code with

   ```
   (function($, undefined) {
     ...
   }) (jQuery);
   ```

Answer (score 7):

did you import the jQuery easing plugin? something like

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

in your page?

Comment: Yeah, when I add that I get an ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined then the original error

Comment: then you also need to add the jQuery itself, just before the easing plugin... i've edit the answer!

Comment: jQuery is not defined is gone, but the original error still remains

Answer (score 5):

```
if(typeof jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] == 'function'){
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
}
```

try this code on swing() function on easing.js

Answer (score 4):

Put jquery.easing.1.3.js to head tag before using plugin or use document.ready

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare the script on the header, call it through jQuery's .getScript() function when the document is fully loaded.

Example:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('path_to_script/easing_script_name.js');
});
</script>
```

The error is due to that jQuery is called before easing script it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Are you importing the jQuery easing plugin? Or anything higher than 1.7.2?

Then just remove that and use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you are calling the WordPress slider plugin's javascript before jQuery or jQuery UI call.

Does it resolve this way?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/wordpress-slider-plugin.js"></script>
```