# Magento - Banner Not working

Tags: php, magento

I have a website on cashmerepoloclub.com and it is not working properly. The banner shows the first slide then stops responding and sometimes it does not show itself. I have tried to replace its original files, enabling it, disabling other unused extensions but nothing works. Can someone help me please?

Thanking you in advance
Akshat Gupta

Comment: Which extension you are using for banner slider?

Comment: It says Magic Banner

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not just link to an external site

Answer (score 0):

Banner is not loading other images because there is jquery.easing

[image]
Search for this error on google jquery-easingjquery-easing-def-is-not-a-function. You can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533168/jquery-easingjquery-easing-def-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I didn't get you sir. can you please explain more as i am a beginner

Comment: check the screen shot

Comment: Sir, I am not able to reproduce the same error on my side. But can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: check the updated answer. I am guessing this is due to easing file. Try to use some cdn. then check and let me know

Comment: I tried putting the entire code between the (function($, undefined) { but it does not work **EDIT 1** i also tried $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: In magento $ denotes prototype. If you are including jquery then you have to do no-Conflicts. Write jQuery(function($){ inside code });

Comment: it is difficult to explain you the whole process here. You can search the error that i have told you and follow the instruction that other guys have told to do.

Answer (score 0):

Source file for jQuery Fancy box is missing. Include jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js in the page header. You can download jQuery Fancy box from [here](http://fancybox.net/)

Then check the issue was resolved. If the banner is still has the issue, then replace the following code

```
jQuery(function(){  
jQuery('#camera_wrap_4').camera({
height: '36%',
loader: 'bar',
pagination:false,
thumbnails:false,
fx         : 'random',
hover:true,
imagePath: '../images/'
});
});
```

with

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(function(){  
jq('#camera_wrap_4').camera({
height: '36%',
loader: 'bar',
pagination:false,
thumbnails:false,
fx         : 'random',
hover:true,
imagePath: '../images/'
});
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: In the downloaded code, you need to take jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js file and  include it in your page head. This may fix the issue. If not, then you have to search for the above given code and replace.

Comment: Solution for replacing the code is a secondary option. Before that you need to add jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js from downloaded package.Otherwise, add the following script in  app/design/frontend/default/<theme>/template/page/html/header.phtml <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>